# Multiple conditions equation

Tags: probability

I want to think about the probability of those who satisfy the following $4$ conditions:

(a) Female. With sample size: ($n=10$)

(b) Has red hair. With sample size: ($n=20$)

(c) Wears glasses. With sample size: ($n=30$)

(d) Is American. With sample size: ($n=40$)

How can I write this as an equation?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is the set of data you are working with?

Comment: Hi, I don't have a particular data but just assuming that I want to find the intersection of those four conditions, let's say, out of 1,000 samples I have. And the size of the sample for each condition will be (a) female n=10, (b) red hair n=20, (c) glasses n=30, and (d) American n=40, respectively.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Simply: 10/100 * 20/100 * 30/100*40/100. But I thought there's going to be more professional probability-like answer to this rather than my equation...

Comment: Could you please provide more information? What you have provided is not enough to provide a sufficient answer.

Comment: Try drawing a Venn diagram or look up Venn diagrams.  That will help you to consider the intersections of sets.  There are formulas that accompany the Venn diagrams lessons.  Usually start with two characteristics, then consider three.  Adding a fourth complicates the formulas, so get comfortable with two and three first.  Do you know the total sample size?